# How to programmatically determine the highest version kernel RPM installed?

Tags: rpm, version

What I want to script is something along the lines of:

```
if [ uname -r is not == highest version of kernel RPM installed ]
then
  echo "You need to reboot to use the latest kernel"
fi
```

The problem is, if the output of `rpm -q kernel` is something like:

```
kernel-2.6.32-358.10.2.el6.x86_64
kernel-2.6.32-358.6.1.el6.x86_64
```

… how do I determine which is higher? I know a simple string sort is not reliable (it will be backwards with this example). Is there a shortcut with rpm or do I have to parse out everything and compare it myself?

Comment: You can use /var/log/yum.log for that. Or 'ls -lht /boot | grep vmlinuz' if the kernel is what you're interested in.

Comment: Those are not reliable methods for determining which is a higher version. Checking /boot might include kernels that are for entirely different multiboot partitions.

Comment: Maybe I'm overthinking it. rpm -q kernel always seems to list kernels in version order. Is that reliable?

Comment: 'ls -lht /boot | grep vmlinuz | grep el6' :)

Comment: And `sort -V` does not give correct result?

Comment: Dingdingding! It may be possible to confuse sort -V with a complicated scheme that requires the rpmdevtools to sort it out, but for the kernel and most versioning schemes I think it does the job! Thanks @Sukminder, I did not know that existed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### TL;DR

The 3rd attempt actually works! I'm leaving the first 2 attempts so that others that may come across this Q&A in the future will hopefully gain some insight into how non-trivial a problem it is to parse RPM version information and determine the lineage of which came first, second, etc.

### Attempt #1 (OP said didn't work)

This command will sort the output and give you them in version order:

```
$ rpm -q kernel --queryformat "%{VERSION} %{RELEASE}\n"|sort -n
2.6.18 238.12.1.el5
2.6.18 238.19.1.el5
2.6.18 274.12.1.el5
2.6.18 308.8.2.el5
```

**WHY IT DIDN'T WORK:** A naive person would think that you can use some variant of the `sort` command to perform this task, but there is enough variability and inconsistency in the formatting of the actual version information for a given RPM that it just isn't up to the task.

### Attempt #2 (OP said didn't work)

```
$ rpm -q --last kernel | head -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f1
kernel-2.6.35.14-106.fc14
```

**WHY IT DIDN'T WORK:** I had high hopes that this approach would yield the results the OP was looking for, but the issue with this one as @Joel pointed out in the comments, is that the `--last` switch is merely returning the results sorted by the date the RPMs were installed.

### Attempt #3

This one will definitely do the job. I found a suite of tools called RPM Development Tools. There are 2 tools in this suite that will give you the capability to determine whether one version of a RPM is newer or older than another.

If the RPM isn't already installed you can do so as follows:

```
yum install rpmdevtools
```

The first tool that's useful is called `rpmdev-vercmp`. This tool can compare 2 names of RPMs and tell you which one is newer. For example:

```
$ rpmdev-vercmp kernel-2.6.35.14-100.fc14.x86_64 kernel-2.6.35.14-103.fc14.x86_64
0:kernel-2.6.35.14-103.fc14.x86_64 is newer
```

After finding this I was all set to put together a shell script but then realized, man I'm lazy, so I poked a few minutes more and found another tool in the suite called `rpmdev-sort`.

This tool is pay-dirt. You can use it as follows:

```
$ rpm -q kernel | rpmdev-sort 
kernel-2.6.35.14-100.fc14.x86_64
kernel-2.6.35.14-103.fc14.x86_64
kernel-2.6.35.14-106.fc14.x86_64
```

There are a lot of tools in RPM Development Tools that might be worth a look for others so I'm listing them here for future reference.

```
$ rpm -q --queryformat '[%{NAME} %{FILEMODES:perms} %{FILENAMES}\n]' rpmdevtools \
    | grep -E "^.* -..x..x..x " \
    | awk '{print $3}'          \
    | sed 's#/usr/bin/##'       \
    | paste - - -               \
    | column -t

annotate-output   checkbashisms    licensecheck
manpage-alert     rpmargs          rpmdev-bumpspec
rpmdev-checksig   rpmdev-cksum     rpmdev-diff
rpmdev-extract    rpmdev-md5       rpmdev-newinit
rpmdev-newspec    rpmdev-packager  rpmdev-rmdevelrpms
rpmdev-setuptree  rpmdev-sha1      rpmdev-sha224
rpmdev-sha256     rpmdev-sha384    rpmdev-sha512
rpmdev-sort       rpmdev-sum       rpmdev-vercmp
rpmdev-wipetree   rpmelfsym        rpmfile
rpminfo           rpmls            rpmpeek
rpmsodiff         rpmsoname        spectool
```

### An alternative to #3

An alternative that the OP mentioned in the comments is to use `sort -V`. That's a capital `-V`. I'd never heard of this switch either. From the `sort` man page:

```
-V, --version-sort
       natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```

As it turns out `sort` does provide a facility to sort version numbers so you could also perform the sorting like so:

```
$ rpm -q kernel | sort -V
kernel-2.6.35.14-100.fc14.x86_64
kernel-2.6.35.14-103.fc14.x86_64
kernel-2.6.35.14-106.fc14.x86_64
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think so. A simple string sort would put kernel-2.6.10 before kernel-2.6.9. This has to work generically, not just for the example.

Comment: -n only helps you with the first number. Try sorting this:
    2.6.18 238.12.1.el5
    2.6.18 238.19.1.el5
    2.6.18 274.12.1.el5
    2.6.18 274.8.2.el5

sort is absolutely the wrong tool here, as well as anything else that doesn't know anything about version-release schemes.

Comment: @slm `--last` sorts by package installation time, it's not necessarily going to be the latest kernel (if they did a manual rpm install of a lower kernel version, for instance).

Comment: This one is starting to feel like a dead horse 8-)

Comment: @sosiouxme - give my latest attempt a try, hopefully it does the job.

Comment: That will work; as it turns out, so does "sort -V" which I'd never heard of. At least, for most uses. These tools are still pretty handy to know about though :)

Comment: Added to the answer. Thanks, never heard of that switch either 8-). BTW, like your blog!

Comment: sort -V thing will fail in one context. Say you wanted to compare 2 versions of a package - 1.15-abc and 1.15-2ab. The sort command would say that 1.15-abc is higher than 1.15-2ab. But infact, for rpm, 2ab is higher than abc.

Comment: sort -V a lot different from rpmdev-sort. I would not use that with rpms at all.
It's ok for a quick glance, but that's it.

Comment: I added it based on feedback from the OP. I'd use rpmdev-sort exclusively.

Comment: I needed a solution that worked on CentOS 5, 6, and 7. My versions of 5 and 6 didn't include rpmdev-sort in the rpmdevtools package, and CentOS 5 didn't even support sort -V. However, I found that I was able to copy the rpmdev-sort script from CentOS 7 and it worked fine on both CentOS 5 and CentOS 6. :)

Answer (score 1):

You really need to use the RPM library to get a good result. The version comparison algorithm is... decidedly complex. It's non-trivial to reimplement in shell, but if you can use Python to do the actual comparison, it becomes relatively straightforward. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206319/how-do-i-compare-rpm-versions-in-python for an exmaple of how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

```
rpm -q kernel --queryformat="%{buildtime}\t%{name}-%{version}-%{release}.%{arch}\n" | sort -nr | head -1 | cut -f2
```

I think sorting by buildtime is less likely to have a corner case where it fails, unlike installtime. However, --last is neater.

Answer (score 1):

Found this thread looking for the same thing but determine the latest kernel version in Ubuntu (16.04 LTS in my case) if it is not yet the current one.

Thanks to @slm this works beautifully for me:

```
ls /lib/modules | sort -V | tail --lines=1
```

> 4.15.0-161-generic

```
uname -r
```

> 4.15.0-159-generic

at the time of this writing.

Answer (score 0):

`--last` won't tell you the highest version number but it will order by date of installation. So you can see the most recently installed version:

```
[root@xms_apps ~]# rpm -qa kernel-xen --last
kernel-xen-2.6.18-348.1.1.el5                 Tue 29 Jan 2013 02:18:52 PM EST
kernel-xen-2.6.18-308.11.1.el5                Fri 20 Jul 2012 04:00:26 PM EDT
kernel-xen-2.6.18-308.8.2.el5                 Wed 20 Jun 2012 03:32:47 PM EDT
```

Most of the time (unless they did a manual kernel install) the two should be the same.

To get it 100% right 100% of the time, you're going to have to get the two kernel versions down to `2.6.*` format then just break it apart starting after the 2.6 (RHEL won't rebase that drastically within a single version, RHEL5 will always be a 2.6 kernel) and just iterate over each line of rpm output (possibly sorted by `--last` for performance) and compare each position against the analogous position in the kernel version you got from `uname -r` if any of the numbers are bigger in the rpm db's string than the uname string, immediately exit with that message.

To help you out there there's a similar question [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023830/bash-how-compare-two-strings-in-version-format). But that function assumes purely dotted decimal notation, so you may compare number position before the hyphen (since there's only one) then use that person's bash function to test if the patch version is higher in `uname` than in the rpm db string.

Answer (score 0):

```
[root@ip-172-31-36-134 ~]# whatis grub2-rpm-sort
grub2-rpm-sort (8)   - Sort input according to RPM version compare.
[root@ip-172-31-36-134 ~]# rpm -qf `which grub2-rpm-sort`
grub2-tools
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Unfortunately it is not at all clear how your answer relates to the question of kernel versions asked by the OP. Please edit your post to clarify.

Comment: Owen, you've pointed to a program named grub2-rpm-sort and to which package contains it, but not "how do I tell if `uname -r` is not the highest kernel RPM level installed". The program *sounds* like it could solve the problem, so if you could just spell that out for the OP, this would be a good answer. Thank you!