# How do I combine the -v and -B switches in grep?

Tags: grep

I have a list of currently installed kernels, and I'm trying to grep out both the currently installed kernel and the previously installed kernel. For this example, linux-image-3.2.0-60-generic is the currently running kernel, and these are the installed kernels:

```
linux-image-3.2.0-49-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-51-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-52-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-53-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-54-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-55-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-56-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-57-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-58-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-59-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-60-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-61-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-63-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-64-generic
```

I can use `grep -v $(uname -r)` to remove the currently running kernel from this list. However, I can't seem to use `grep -v -B 1 $(uname -r)` to remove current and previous kernel from the list. Is there a way to combine the `-B` and `-v`? Or am I approaching this entirely from the wrong direction?

Comment: `-B N` means to print `N` lines before the lines that are printed. When used with `-v`, it means to print lines before the lines that DON'T match. Which basically means that it will `N` lines that match the regexp before each non-matching line.

Comment: I think you should be able to do what you want with `awk` pretty easily. Save the previous line in a variable. When you read a line that doesn't match the current version, print the saved line, and put the current line in the variable. When you read a line that DOES match the current version, clear the variable and don't print anything. Finally, print the saved line in the END block.

Comment: From where you get the list of kernels as output? Is it from any file?

Comment: No, it's from some crazy grepping: `dpkg -l linux-image-[0-9]* | grep "ii  " |  grep -oE linux-image-[a-zA-Z0-9.\-]\{0,\}`. This only works on Debian-based systems, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 2 grep's to get what you want. The interior `grep` will generate the "list" of matches for the current kernel, `uname -r` and the previous reversion to it. The exterior `grep` will give you the list of kernels excluding these 2.

```
$ grep -v "$(grep -B 1 "$(uname -r)" list.txt)" list.txt
```

#### Example

To simulate what you have I've added the contents of these to the file `list.txt`.

```
$ cat list.txt 
linux-image-3.2.0-49-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-51-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-52-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-53-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-54-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-55-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-56-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-57-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-58-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-59-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-60-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-61-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-63-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-64-generic
```

Now let's pretend that the command `uname -r` returns this string:

```
$ uname -r
3.2.0-60-generic
```

So when I run this command I get a list of the kernels minus the `uname -r` and the version previous to it.

```
$ grep -v "$(grep -B 1 "3.2.0-60-generic" list.txt)" list.txt 
linux-image-3.2.0-49-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-51-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-52-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-53-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-54-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-55-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-56-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-57-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-58-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-61-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-63-generic
linux-image-3.2.0-64-generic
```

This all assumes that the list of kernels in `list.txt` is in a sorted format.

#### Additional tips

If you're interested, I wrote up a A to this Q&A titled: [How to programmatically determine the highest version kernel RPM installed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76597/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-highest-version-kernel-rpm-installed/76601#76601) where I show how you can parse out versions of kernels using `sort -V`.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned the list, I assume it is in some file. Nevertheless, the command can be easily modified.

A simpler approach would be,

```
current_ver=$(uname -r)
awk "/$current_ver/{y=1;next}y" list
```

The `current_ver` variable stores the current kernel version. The `awk` command gets the output after the current version.

**P.S:**

I am not pretty well versed in `awk`. The command can sure be further enhanced :)

Answer (score 1):

Since we are definitely working with linux here you might use GNU `ls` to `-v`ersion sort results. Considering that and that your kernel file-names are unlikely to contain any weird characters you could do:

```
ls -1v /boot/linux-image* | grep "$(uname -r)" -B1
```