# Remove line matching a pattern if next line doesn't match another pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

Below is extract output from my check script which I would like to print only hostname and error. If there is no error for host delete the entry of hostname too.
The logic I want to use is delete existing line if next line doesn't match "NOT OK"
May use `awk` or `sed`...any utility is good for pattern matching.

```
NSAS_HOST:d01-emsacssb01
NSAS_HOST:d01-emsacssb02
NSAS_HOST:emsacssbcon01
NOT OK main load processes
NOT OK 5.3% AXConfigurator
NOT OK eth0.orig is not UP, but ifcfg-eth0.orig sets ONBOOT=yes
NOT OK eth1.bak is not UP, but ifcfg-eth1.bak sets ONBOOT=yes
NOT OK eth1.orig is not UP, but ifcfg-eth1.orig sets ONBOOT=yes
NSAS_HOST:emsacssb03
NOT OK eth0.orig is not UP, but ifcfg-eth0.orig sets ONBOOT=yes
NOT OK eth1.orig is not UP, but ifcfg-eth1.orig sets ONBOOT=yes
NSAS_HOST:emsacsnb01
NSAS_HOST:emsacsnb02
NSAS_HOST:d02-emsacssb01
NSAS_HOST:d02-emsacssb02
NSAS_HOST:b2bcms01
NSAS_HOST:b2bcms02
NSAS_HOST:d02-b2bpgdb01
NOT OK bond0: device speed not determined
NOT OK bond1: device speed not determined
```

Expected result:

```
NSAS_HOST:emsacssbcon01
NOT OK main load processes
NOT OK 5.3% AXConfigurator
NOT OK eth0.orig is not UP, but ifcfg-eth0.orig sets ONBOOT=yes
NOT OK eth1.bak is not UP, but ifcfg-eth1.bak sets ONBOOT=yes
NOT OK eth1.orig is not UP, but ifcfg-eth1.orig sets ONBOOT=yes
NSAS_HOST:emsacssb03
NOT OK eth0.orig is not UP, but ifcfg-eth0.orig sets ONBOOT=yes
NOT OK eth1.orig is not UP, but ifcfg-eth1.orig sets ONBOOT=yes
NSAS_HOST:d02-b2bpgdb01
NOT OK bond0: device speed not determined
NOT OK bond1: device speed not determined
```

Basically:
1. search for term `NSAS_HOST`
2. check next line for `NOT OK`. If it exists print lines until we reach the next `NSAS_HOST`
3. If `NOT OK` doesn't exist just delete the `NSAS_HOST` line

Comment: Probably helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134915/how-do-i-combine-the-v-and-b-switches-in-grep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with sed :

```
sed -ne '/NSAS_HOST/{N;/NOT OK/{p}};/NSAS_HOST/!p' FILE
```

OUTPUT:

```
NSAS_HOST:emsacssbcon01
NOT OK main load processes
NOT OK 5.3% AXConfigurator
NOT OK eth0.orig is not UP, but ifcfg-eth0.orig sets ONBOOT=yes
NOT OK eth1.bak is not UP, but ifcfg-eth1.bak sets ONBOOT=yes
NOT OK eth1.orig is not UP, but ifcfg-eth1.orig sets ONBOOT=yes
NSAS_HOST:emsacssb03
NOT OK eth0.orig is not UP, but ifcfg-eth0.orig sets ONBOOT=yes
NOT OK eth1.orig is not UP, but ifcfg-eth1.orig sets ONBOOT=yes
NSAS_HOST:d02-b2bpgdb01
NOT OK bond0: device speed not determined
NOT OK bond1: device speed not determined
```

Comment: this logic has a problem. how about like first two NSAS_HOST lines and then NOT OK.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `sed` for this job:

```
sed '/NSAS_HOST/{$d;N;/\n.*NOT OK/!D;}' infile
```

This just pulls in the `N`ext line on each line that matches `NSAS_HOST` (except if on the la`$`t line when it `d`eletes the pattern space). If the 2nd line in the pattern space does not match `NOT OK`, it `D`eletes up to the newline (that is, it deletes the 1st line in the pattern space) and restarts the cycle.

Comment: @Wildcard - that doesn't work either (I could explain why but it's too long)... I usually don't use `n` and `h`/`H` together, so I would probably run `sed '/NSAS_HOST/{h;d;};/NOT OK/{x;/NSAS_HOST/G;//!x;}'`

Comment: My alternate approaches didn't work correctly; I'm removing them.  Thanks for pointing out the interaction between `-n` and the `n` command.

Answer (score 0):

It's so easy in GNU grep using [the `--no-group-separator` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Context-Line-Control-1) in addition to the `-B` option:

```
grep --no-group-separator -B1 ^"NOT OK" log
```

Or, if your `grep` doesn't have `--no-group-separator`, but does have `-B`, then to remove the `--` lines between individual groups:

```
grep -B1 ^"NOT OK" log | grep -v ^--$
```

Comment: 1. This works with the input sample (that is, all lines match either `NSAS_HOST` or `NOT OK`) but if there are other lines (that need to be preserved) this won't print them. 2. You don't need the second `grep`: use `--no-group-separator`

Comment: Wow, "hidden" feature! It isn't in the manual.