# Bash script to verify that an rpm is at least at a given version

Tags: linux, bash, rpm, version

I need to write a script to verify that an RPM is at least a given version in Linux.

- **QUESTION 1:** How can I get the RPM version in a variable $RPM_VERSION, so that it contains the version all the way to ".src.rpm"?
- **QUESTION 2:** What is the best approach to compare the 2 versions?

For example: rpm-4.2-9.69.src.rpm compared to rpm-4.14-0.69.src.rpm. This is my attempt, but it doesn't work:

```
STR_BASE_ACCEPTABLE_VER="rpm-4.2-0.69.src.rpm"

if  [[ "$RPM_VERSION" < "$STR_BASE_ACCEPTABLE_VER" ]]; then   
    echo "$RPM_VERSION is too low..."  \
else   
    echo "$RPM_VERSION is fine"  \
fi
```

Comment: Useful: [How to programmatically determine the highest version kernel RPM installed?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76597/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-highest-version-kernel-rpm-installed/76601#76601)

Answer (score 8):

### Parsing versions

#### Hackey way

For the first part, I'd query RPM for the particular version info like so.

```
$ rpm -qi vim-enhanced | grep Version
Version     : 7.4.417
```

You can then parse this out like so:

```
$ rpm -qi vim-enhanced | awk -F': ' '/Version/ {print $2}'
7.4.417
```

This can be captured into a variable like so:

```
$ RPM_VERSION=$(rpm -qi vim-enhanced | awk -F': ' '/Version/ {print $2}')

$ echo $RPM_VERSION
7.4.417
```

#### Using queryformats

The `rpm` tool also provides a facility called `--queryformat` which allows you to customize the output that it generates. Knowing this you can tell `rpm` to print the "VERSION" macro like so:

```
$ rpm -q --queryformat '%{VERSION}' vim-enhanced
7.4.417
```

Putting it to a variable:

```
$ RPM_VERSION=$(rpm -q --queryformat '%{VERSION}' vim-enhanced)
```

**NOTE:** You can see all the query tags using the `--querytags` switch to `rpm`, for example:

```
$ rpm --querytags | head -5
ARCH
ARCHIVESIZE
BASENAMES
BUGURL
BUILDARCHS
```

### Comparing versions

To do the comparing is going to be trickier. Luckily there's a tool in the `rpmdevtools` package called `rpmdev-vercmp` that can assist you greatly.

#### Usage

```
$ rpmdev-vercmp --help

rpmdev-vercmp <epoch1> <ver1> <release1> <epoch2> <ver2> <release2>
rpmdev-vercmp <EVR1> <EVR2>
rpmdev-vercmp # with no arguments, prompt

Exit status is 0 if the EVR's are equal, 11 if EVR1 is newer, and 12 if EVR2
is newer.  Other exit statuses indicate problems.
```

If you notice the exit statuses that it returns, you can find out which version is newer simply by asking this tool, giving it the 2 names of the RPM's.

#### Example

```
$ rpmdev-vercmp rpm-4.2-9.69 rpm-4.14-0.69
rpm-4.2-9.69 < rpm-4.14-0.69
$ echo $?
12
```

So based on the exit code of 12, the 2nd argument would be the newer of the 2.

### Putting it together

Your solution would then look something like this:

```
rpmdev-vercmp $RPM_VERSION $STR_BASE_ACCEPTABLE_VER > /dev/null
if [[ $? == 12 ]]; then
  echo "$RPM_VERSION is too low..."
else 
  echo "$RPM_VERSION is fine"
fi
```

Then if we were to set variables like so:

```
$ STR_BASE_ACCEPTABLE_VER="rpm-4.2-9.69"
$ RPM_VERSION="rpm-4.14-0.69"

$ ./cmp_rpmvers.bash    
rpm-4.14-0.69 is fine
```

IF I swap them:

```
$ STR_BASE_ACCEPTABLE_VER="rpm-4.14-0.69"
$ RPM_VERSION="rpm-4.2-9.69"

$ ./cmp_rpmvers.bash
rpm-4.2-9.69 is too low...
```

Comment: Thanks for the good info. 
I still need help

FOR QUESTION 1:

$ rpm_version=$(rpm -q --queryformat '%{VERSION}' bash
gives me:  4.1.2

What I would like, is the Source RPM version. 

For example,  for bash-4.1.2-15.el6_4.2.src.rpm I would get 4.1.2-15.el6_4.2 (all the way to src.rpm)
so that I can compare to a closely related release.

Comment: FOR QUESTION 2:
I don't have access to rpmdev-vercmp in my Linux platform, and I cannot install new components.
Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: @bashquestion - look at the querytags. The version bits in the name of the RPM is constructed from other querytags. For eg. `%{EVR}`. Without `rpmdev-vercmp` you'll have to parse the strings manually or use `sort -V` command as I show in my other A that I liked to in the comments above.

Answer (score 2):

For **Question #2** (if you don't have rpmdevtools and cannot install it):

On minimal installation you still should have yum, thus you should also have python and rpm python package. Then comparing 2 versions could look like this:

```
python -c "import sys,rpm; print rpm.labelCompare((None, '$VER1', '$REL1'), (None, '$VER2', '$REL2'));"
```

Given "rpm-4.14-0.69" package name, $VER is a version part (4.14), and $REL is a release part (0.69). You can extract them by splitting package name by '-'. I put None for epoch parts here as your example does not contain epoch in the package name.

The result of labelCompare will be 0, 1 or -1.

Actually, you could just try to download rpmdev-vercmp or rpmdev-sort (https://fedorahosted.org/releases/r/p/rpmdevtools/) and use them w/o installing rpmdevtools, as these are simple python scripts.